# CA Arcserve Configuration

Tags: backup

I am setting up an installation of CA arcserve 12.5 for network backups.

I ran a trial run of the backups over the weekend and noticed that each backup waited for the prior to complete. At the moment I have one File System Device which I was going to use for all of our servers. The FSD is assigned to one media pool.

Is this incorrect? I set it up this way as I thought it didn't make sense to make a new FSD and media pool for each server.

I have 5 servers I would like to backup in parralell each weekend, in this situation do I need a different FSD and Media pool for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off my condolences for using Arcserve (I'm stuck w/ it right now and hate it). We have different media pools for stuff like (2weekstaging, 2wkstag_daily, 2wkstaging_mthly, etc.). Our setup is that staging is a VTL before doing migration jobs to tape. The diff pools are needed for each job, not server.